# ConvertCsvToXml does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, csv

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //read in file data and calculate record number
        string csv = File.ReadAllText("File-Path");
        int testing = 1;

        XDocument doc = ConvertCsvToXml(csv, new[] { "\t" });

        //create array of record number
        WebService.Function[] xxx = new WebService.Function[1];

        recordAmount = 0;
```

Hi there for some reason in the above code the ConvertCsvToXml line is bringing back an exception saying it does not exist, and the intelisense brings up nothing after typing XDocument.

What can I do to resolve this? There are no errors in my code other than this!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where is ConvertCsvToXml defined? that isn't a BCL method...

Comment: It hasnt been defined and not entirely sure where to define it :( I have got this to work in another program before.

Comment: well, you'll need to write that method *somewhere*...

Comment: You should have a look at the other project where you used the function before, and see where it comes from.

Comment: Right I have done it now thanks for that you were all right I feel sheepish :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define the ConvertCsvToXml method in the same class as the button2_Click method.

Comment: ok so what is the best way of doing that in a code example if possible?